# For loop to perform action for json dict keys with If statement to filter output before appending output to list?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, for-loop, steam

I am using the Steam web API and `requests` to get a list of a user's owned games, then putting the `json` response into a dictionary like so (AppID : Game Name). I would then like to process each AppID as a variable in a `requests.get` for steamapis.com web API to get additional info for each app, which is also returned in `json`. Finally I would like to incorporate an `If` statement that filters the response for each AppID, checking for category/description containing "Multiplayer/Co-op/other tag/etc," and if found adds the Game Name associated with each AppID to a list.

I just can't seem to figure out the logic and syntax.

```
import requests

# get owned games
oresponse = requests.get(f"https://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v0001/?key={steam_key}&steamid={steam_id}&format=json")
owned_games = oresponse.json()

# Extract the list of app IDs from the response
ogames_list = [game["appid"] for game in owned_games["response"]["games"]]

# Get the list of all multiplayer or co-op games available on Steam
for game in ogames_list:
    mresponse = requests.get(f"https://api.steamapis.com/market/app/{game}?api_key={steam_key}")
    if any(tag["description"] == "Multi-player" for tag in tags):
        multiplayer_games.append(app_name)

print(list(multiplayer_games))
```

Comment: Where is the `AppID: Game Name` dictionary?

Comment: What is the problem with the code you posted? The `if` logic looks OK to me.

Comment: Where do you set `tags` and `app_name`? Are those supposed to come from `mresponse.json()`?

Comment: You seem to have left out important parts of the code, I don't see how we can help with it.